# SSIS Script Task (Not working when Scheduled)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have as SSIS Package with a script task. The task works great in Visual Studio 2015. However when I deploy the package and run it via SSMS the task script shows sucessful, but it runs extremely quickly and the file is not created. My code is farily simple (Grabs a file from a url, and saves it to a network location)

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    Dim url, destination As String
    destination = Dts.Variables("StagingPath").Value.ToString + Dts.Variables("DeliveryFile").Value.ToString
    url = Dts.Variables("ReportURL").Value.ToString

    'Delete staging file if it exists
    Try
        If IO.File.Exists(destination) Then IO.File.Delete(destination)

        Dim result As Boolean = SaveFile(url, destination)
        If result = True Then
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
        Else
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Function SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String) As Boolean
    Dim loRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim loResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
    Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.Stream
    Dim loFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
    Dim laBytes(256) As Byte
    Dim liCount As Integer = 1
    Try
        loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        loRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        loRequest.Timeout = 600000
        loRequest.Method = "GET"
        loResponse = CType(loRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream
        Do While liCount > 0
            liCount = loResponseStream.Read(laBytes, 0, 256)
            loFileStream.Write(laBytes, 0, liCount)
        Loop
        loFileStream.Flush()
        loFileStream.Close()

        'Success
        SaveFile = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        SaveFile = False
    End Try
End Function
```

Like I said, everything is fine when run locally but not when deployed to SSISDB Catalog. The url passed is to a local resource on our SSRS Server, that is a pdf file.

Comment: Check your rights to your sql agent service account user.

Comment: like @plaidDK said. Specifically the internet side of Agent service account

Comment: it's a success because you try catch hits the catch. You can write out your error message somewhere from the catch.

Comment: @plaidDK I'm running the package in SSMS By right clicking and choosing exexute. That runs it under my credentials. I don't think it's the agent account.

Comment: @KeithL I simplified this. And the script now just assigns a value to a read/write variable and returns. When I run in Visual Studio again it runs fine, on the SSSIDB Catalog the value never gets set. But the script shows as succesful.

Comment: I found that when I deploy it to the SSISDB, I must deploy the whole project whenever I make changes to the script. I was only deploying the single .dtsx file in the past. I don't really like this behaiviour. As I have about 30 packages for this project. If i'm making other changes to other packages they are not always ready to be deployed. I'm glad I found a soluttion, but this is not really ideal.

Comment: I find that deploying a single package works fine for me.   Maybe there is a different root cause than what you think.

Comment: @TabAlleman No, you cant single deploy when you already project deployed. Then it wont take your changes.

Comment: @BillSchanks Then you should convert your SSIS model project to package deployment project and not project deployment.

Comment: @plaidDK you can with 2016+ .. I've done it and it works for me:   http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2015/11/05/ssis-2016-supports-single-package-deployment.aspx   Since OP is using Visual Studio 2015, I assume he's using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3676/sql-server-integration-services-2016-incremental-package-deployment/

Comment: Yes.. Visual Studio 2015, with SQL2016.

Comment: I've always used the package deployment method, and with this project used project deployment. Didn't realize you couldn't single deploy a package this way. However, I see you can based on the blog post.. but there must be a bug with script tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to deploy the whole project whenever I had a change to the script task, or the script task will not even attempt to run but reports as running sucessfully.